# Filter design for high power voltages Partial discharge detector

Tags: power, filter, partial-discharge, corona

Hell all,
I have a signal imposed on a 60Hz 800V AC voltage that I need to retrieve via MCU. The signal is in the range of 10KHz to 50KHz with peak to peak voltage ranging from 5 to 50 volts . The signal waveform is as can be seen in attached image. I have never worked with such high voltages before and tried a few methods to retrieve signal however I failed. (I tried dividing the voltage and and taking a sample however that failed, I tried a transformer however the signal was lost in the transformer and more noise was introduced).
This signal is that of a Partial discharge/corona that I need to detect for an extremely small part in a certain environment.
My question is as follows, are there any active amplifier designs that handle high voltages, up to 1kv. Also, where can I find such high voltage components?
Any design suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
[image: PD signal imposed on hipot voltage]

Thanks in advance for all your tips.

Comment: That's all very interesting, Sam, but you forgot to ask a question. Are you looking for design help? Welcome to EE.SE. Ask it in the original post. If you just want above 10 kHz then a high-pass RC filter (of suitable voltage rating) seems like it would do the job.

Comment: A differential DSO probe for example can do that. Ar you can use a resistor divider + ADC + very good isolation between MCU and adc circuit. You may look to Silicon LAbs, they produce some HV components.

Comment: What is a DSO probe?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a ferite core can give you also a good result. As an example you have a resistor chain (or one long HV resistor) and capacitor that at 50Hz has big reactance, while at 50Khz acts like a short. Resitor limits the current, and the trasformer acts like a CT, main purpose is a galvanic isolation. Probably you have tried with some iron core xformer which can't transfer HF due to core loss.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCc9uI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're only interested in the high frequency part and can afford some drift and non-linearity, I'd recommend a voltage divider where you have a capacitor as the HV element (basically a high-pass filter), that way you get all the high frequency stuff but not the 60Hz stuff. C2 is there to keep the whole thing acting more like a voltage divider. You may have to play with the values until you get a decent signal response.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ln1s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: C1 must be a safety part like Y rated or 2 Y rated caps in series

Comment: Yes, thanks @Autistic, I forgot about that. Y caps can handle a lot more abuse than regular caps while under high AC voltages, they are a lot more rugged than ordinary capacitors..

Comment: I don't get the purpose of C2.  But I was going to suggest a high pass filter... get rid of 60 Hz and pass 10 kHz and above... maybe put the corner at 1 kHz.  And then in place of C2, something to limit the voltage there (in case something "let's go") Like a TVS diode or some HV zeners back to back.

Comment: My problem is that I cant find components that would function at the voltage I am interested in.

Comment: C2 forms the second half of a capacitive voltage divider, wi5hout it you'd end up with the derivative of your signal of interest, R1 is there only to get rid of all the low frequency stuff, it's much the same principle as AC coupling on an oscilloscope. If you can't find a single part with a high enough rating, there's not really a problem with stringing several in series, especially Y caps as they are well overengineered to begin with so slight imbalances due to manufacturing tollerances are not going to cause problems